# Calculating percentage from dplyr's filter function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
df <- tibble(
  "result" = c("win", "loss", "win", "win", "loss", "win", "win", "loss"),
  "team" = c("TBL", "NJD", "TBL", "STL", "TBL", "STL", "NJD", "STL"),
)
```

The table has two columns - `result` and `team`. I want to calculate the percentage that a team has "win" as the result. I used `dplyr` to do a quick count of each result, "win" or "loss" -

```
df_win <- df %>% 
  group_by(result, team) %>% 
  filter(result == "win") %>% 
  summarise(count = n())

df_loss <- df %>% 
  group_by(result, team) %>% 
  filter(result == "loss") %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

I want to use `mutate` to create a formula to calculate the number of times the team had a "win" (and conversely for "loss):

```
df %>%
  mutate(team_win_perc = ((df_win / df_loss) * 0.1 )))
```

But obviously one can't just multiply two tables together without consequences:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

Asking as the moron I sometimes am, how do I format this?

Answer (score 2):

Does this produce what you want?

```
df %>% 
  group_by(team) %>% 
  summarise(win_pct = sum(result == "win") / n())
```